# SonataNewsBundle - comments - add status to filters

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Default in SonataNewsBundle CommentAdmin is:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('message')
    ;
}
```

In **protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)** is:

```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        if (!$this->isChild()) {
            $formMapper->add('post', 'sonata_type_model_list');
//            $formMapper->add('post', 'sonata_type_admin', array(), array('edit' => 'inline'));
        }

        $commentClass = $this->commentManager->getClass();

        $formMapper
            ->add('name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('url', null, array('required' => false))
            ->add('message')
            ->add('status', 'choice', array('choices' => $commentClass::getStatusList(), 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))
        ;
    }
```

I try add to filters:

```
->add('status', null, array('label' => 'Status'), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
```

but this throw exception:

```
The options "expanded", "multiple" do not exist.
```

I tried also:
            ->add('status', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(

```
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.status = :status');
                $queryBuilder->setParameter('status', $value);

                return true;
            },
            'field_type' => 'choice'
        ))
```

This now show error, but select is empty. How can i add for this list statuses?
I get examples from [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html)

Maybe is better way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong order of parameter given by calling the add() method.
Try the following:

```
$filters->add('status', null, array(), 'choice', array('choices' => $commentClass::getStatusList(), 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))
```

The form options were set on the 5th parameter.